# Entity relationships designations vs database cardinality

Tags: database, model, relationship, erd

We have to differentiate entity-relationships.

I have a problem to understand one thing:

Is relation one to multiple or one to many (1:M) the same thing as 1:N?
And, M:N is the same as N:M?

Why is it not called M:M (Multiple to Multiple)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is a lot of different terms and notations to identify and illustrate the relationships in a database.  Here is quick summary :

**One to many**

This term is used to represent a `1:n` relationship (or a `0:n` if it is optional).  For instance one author (parent entity) wrote many books (child entities).

This can be modelized like this :

```
+--------------+  +--------------+
| Author       |  | Book         |
+--------------+  +--------------+
| PK  AuthorId |  | PK  BookId   |
|     Name     |  |     Title    |
|              |  |     ISBN     |
+--------------+  | FK  AuthorId |
                  +--------------+
```

**Many to one**

This is the same than `1:n` (or `0:n`) but from the child entity point of view.  For instance, many books written by one author.

**Many to many**

This is coined as a `n:m` in database terms. For instance, two or more authors could be the cowriters of a book or many books.

A very common way to modelize a relationship like this is to use a third table to *link* all the different relationships between the two entities.  In that case, you would probably end up with something like this :

```
+--------------+  +--------------+  +--------------+
| Author       |  | AuthorBook   |  | Book         |
+--------------+  +--------------+  +--------------+       
| PK  AuthorId |  | FK  AuthorId |  | PK  BookId   |   
|     Name     |  | FK  BookId   |  |     Title    |      
|              |  +--------------+  |     ISBN     |
+--------------+                    +--------------+
```

Where AuthorBook has a compound primary key with `AuthorId` and `BookId`.

By the way, I've never heard the term *multiple to multiple*.